# Add a Radio Button to Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

```
Rey[v_, roh_, dia_, muh_] := (roh*v*dia)/muh;
nu[pr_, re_] := pr*re;

Manipulate[
 Row[{
   StringJoin["Re:", ToString[Style[Rey[v, roh, dia, muh], 20]]],
   StringJoin["Nu:", ToString[Style[nu[pr, re], 14]]]}
  ],
 Text[Style["Re & Nu number calculator", 16]],
 Delimiter,
 {{v, 1.5, "Ve "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},
 {{roh, 1, "roh "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},
 {{dia, 0.01, "D"}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},
 {{muh, 0.00089, "Vis "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},
 {{pr, 1.5, "Pr "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},
 {{re, 1000, "Ld "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5},
 Delimiter,
 Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}]],
 LabelStyle -> {14}, ContentSize -> 200,
 TrackedSymbols :> All
]
```

The above code displays the `Re` and `Nu` values based on the user's inputs. I need to add two features to this dashboard:

1. Add a radio button to select whether to display `Re` or `Nu`.
2. The last two input fields, `Pr` and `Ld`, are only used to calculate `Nu`, so I would like to display them only when the user presses the `Nu` button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the first four inputs only apply to Re, so it seems like you would want to only show those when the user selects "Re". Maybe I misunderstood, but here's an attempt:

```
Manipulate[
  Switch[
    displayChoice,
    "Re", StringJoin["Re:", ToString[Style[Rey[v, roh, dia, muh], 20]]],
    "Nu", StringJoin["Nu:", ToString[Style[nu[pr, re], 14]]]],
  Text[Style["Re & Nu number calculator", 16]],
  Delimiter,
  TabView[
    {{"Re",
      "Re" ->
        Column[
          {Control[{{v, 1.5, "Ve "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5}],
           Control[{{roh, 1, "roh "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5}],
           Control[{{dia, 0.01, "D"}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5}],
           Control[{{muh, 0.00089, "Vis "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5}]}]},
     {"Nu",
      "Nu" ->
        Column[
          {Control[{{pr, 1.5, "Pr "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5}],
           Control[{{re, 1000, "Ld "}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 5}]}]}},
    Dynamic[displayChoice]],
  LabelStyle -> {14}, 
  ContentSize -> 200, 
  TrackedSymbols :> All, 
  ControlPlacement -> {Top, Left}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Lericr, Can we do that with Radio button?